# unable to re-render the backbone view after saving the model

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, backbone.js

I save the model and I get a ok response from the server side that the DB is updated. What I'm trying to do is to refetch the collection and update the view with the saved model's information. I'm missing something minor but I just can't figure it out.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
window.App = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {}
};

window.template = function(id){
    return _.template( $('#' + id).html() );
};


// Person Model
App.Models.Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: null,
        question: null,
        quizid: null,
        answerid: null
    },
     url: function() {
            return 'myurl/';
        }
});


App.Collections.People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.Person,
    url: 'myurl/'

});



App.Views.People = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',

    render: function(){
        this.collection.each(function(person){
            var personView = new App.Views.Person({ model: person });
            this.$el.append(personView.render().el);
        }, this);

        return this;
    }
});


App.Views.Person = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    template: template('personTemplate'),
    events: {
     "click #saveButton" : "savedata",
    },


    savedata: function(event){
        //alert(this.model.get("id") + " " + $('#title').val());
                var newModel = new App.Models.Person();
                newModel.save({id: this.model.get("id"), question: $('#title').val()}, {
                    wait : true,
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        error: function (model, response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    }
                );
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});



var peopleCollection = new App.Collections.People;
peopleCollection.fetch({
    success: function(){
    var peopleView = new App.Views.People({collection: peopleCollection});
  $('body').append(peopleView.render().el);
}});


var pw = new peopleView({collection: personCollection});
pw.render();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to refresh view after editing model data then you have to listen for a `sync` or `change` event and rerender the view.

```
App.Views.Person = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(params) {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);
    }
});
```

In case you are adding a brand new model then you need to add it to the collection just after creating.

```
newModel.save({id: this.model.get("id"), question: $('#title').val()} //...
this.collection.add(newModel)
```

and listen for `add` event in people view

```
this.lisenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.render

App.Views.People = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function(params) {
       this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add remove sync', this.render);
   },

   render: function(){
       this.$el.empty();

       this.collection.each(function(person){
            var personView = new App.Views.Person({ model: person });
            this.$el.append(personView.render().el);
        }, this);

       return this;
    }
});
```

Refetching whole collection is redundant in that case.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work. I still have to refresh manually to see the change.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that you are editing your model. Please see an updated answer

Comment: unfortunately once again it doesn't update the view, plus with the added bit of code it loads the data twice on page load. I think the this.controller.add(newModel) bit does not get processed for some reason. When I place that line right underneath newModel.save I get syntax error, I place it in success, then it is not processed.

Comment: Please attach demo on jsbin etc. There is `$el.empty()` to avoid data duplication

Comment: I get error with the following code, this.controller.add(myModel) line.

`savedata: function(event){
  myModel.save({id: myModel.get("id"), question: $('#title').val(), quizid: null, answerid:null},{
  this.collection.add(myModel);
   wait : true,
   success: function (response) {
    alert(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function (model, response) {
     alert(response.responseText);
    }
   }
  );
 },`

Comment: This code doesn't make sens. You can not insert `this.collection.add(myModel);` inside object declaration. In addition do not forget to pass collection as param.

Comment: where should I add that line then? Because the add needs to succeed to trigger the render function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99428/discussion-between-prcube-and-mateusz-nowak).

Comment: http://jsbin.com/qihizodize/edit?js,output Take a look at working demo. You only need to add sync with server.